# DB script or SP which will traverse in all the schemas of DB and provide an specific output in pgsql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to pgSql, and want a query or SP which will provide the following output.

We have a DB with name DB1 and in that DB we have different schemas for different tenants like manufacturing, retail etc.

The schemas can be obtained by:

```
SELECT schema_name
FROM information_schema.schemata 
where schema_owner='test' order by schema_name
```

Every schema have tables with name table1, table2 and table3. In all these 3 tables we have a column boolean published.

So my problem is, I want to know those schemas which have published flag as false in either of the 3 tables.

Problem statement: Write a script/SP which will traverse in all the schemas of DB and will output the list of schemas which are having published column value as ‘false’ in table1, table2 & table3.

Comment: How can a column have a value? A column has a name and is part of a table with many records. Any one of those records could have a value of `false` in that column. Can you clarify what mean here?

Comment: A column with datatype boolean have a value either true or false. I want those who have a column value as False in either of the 3 tables.

Comment: Column name is "published" and Value should be false. means something like if any one or more value of column published is false return the schema name. No need to check if we found any one as false.

Comment: So like... if we did: `SELECT min(published) FROM <some table>` and it returns `0` then we know there is at least one false and we should output that table?